# Storing Object in the Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do this:

```
Entity e = new Entity(_key);
e.setProperty(OBJECT, obj); 
_ds.put(e); // put to the database
```

However, the datastore `_ds` puts some widening in the object such that when I put a `Integer` into the `Entity` property what is returned is a `Long`? Why is that?

Is there a way to store object "as-is" in the Datastore without widening or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you using [Objectify framework](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/).
This is perfect framework for Java App Engine

Answer (score 0):

I thikn it's in the nature of Google App Engine to widen Integer to Long. I had this problem also. So I made:

- [MapDS](http://bit.ly/ZeoX7R)

A simple Java Map interface to the GAE Datastore. It returns just about any kind of Object, Integer, Long, etc. without "widening" or whatsoever.